# Is there a way in SQL Database (Paas) to insert or to peek a message from an Azure Storage Queue?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage-queues

From an On Premise server or even from a VM in Azure (Iaas) I can do it using CLR function,
But what about SQL Database (Paas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following thread for the longer answer:

[Does or does not SQL Azure support CLR assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342550/does-or-does-not-sql-azure-support-clr-assemblies)

Not supported at this time - although we're looking at support in Managed Instances (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/06/13/azure-sql-databases-in-logical-servers-elastic-pools-and-managed-instances/).