# Is there no way to use CLR Assembly in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm using since SQL Server 2012 that support CLR Assembly trigger (coded with C#).

But I'm now finding possibility to move Azure SQL but it says CLR Assembly is not supported.

Is it sure that Azure SQL doesn't support CLR Assembly and no way to do it?

```
Msg 10341, Level 16, State 100, Line 5
Assembly 'MyProject.SQLCLR' cannot be loaded because Azure SQL Database does not support user-defined assemblies. Contact Azure Technical Support if you have questions.
```

I also found this article but unclear for me.

[Does or does not SQL Azure support CLR assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342550/does-or-does-not-sql-azure-support-clr-assemblies)

Comment: Looks like you can compile your dll locally then run [CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM BINARY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) sql with the binary bytes of the dll loaded into a VARBINARY variable (you cannot access the file system on azure sql db). Show the sql you used to get your error message

Comment: The information in the link is pretty clear - SQL CLR is not supported.

Comment: @gotqn what you you mean by "the link" and "the information"?

Comment: @CaiusJard Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342550/does-or-does-not-sql-azure-support-clr-assemblies - check the answer.

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, there is no SQL CLR for `SQL Database`.

Comment: There is for Managed Instance. Things in technology move on; it doesn't always pay to heed an ancient answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) indicates that an sql like:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SomeName
FROM 0x...
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
```

will work; all you have to do is turn your dll into a string of hexadecimal number pairs representing the bytes and put them in where the ... are. The example is at the very bottom of the MSDN doc. It would be important to note though that that doc explicitly states its advice is applicable to Azure SQL Managed Instance which is a relatively recent provision; ensure that is what you have deployed. See [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/03/07/what-is-azure-sql-database-managed-instance-2/) for a more in depth discussion

Comment: Hi Caius, Thanks for the answer.
I also created assembly like that.
But it doens't work on Azure SQL.

Comment: Is your Azure SQL a Managed Instance or is it an older deployment? From what I read this only works on manged instance

Comment: Dear Caius, I didn't know there were "Sql database" and "Sql managed Instance" both. Really thanks and sorry for my short confirmation. Now I'm trying to do it with managed instance. I will let you know the result

Comment: Dear Caius, I suceeded with managed instance. CLR works fine! Thanks