# Azure - Enable/Disable database setting for security purposes

Tags: sql, database, azure, t-sql, database-security

We have certain security requirements in order for our app to go live within our orgainisation.

We are using the Microsoft azure platform to host the application along with a Azure SQL server and database. To meet these security requirements, we need to configure settings on the server/database.

However we are running into issues using the default azure SQL server/database.
Here is an example. We need to "Disable 'clr enabled' option".
We have tried the following:

```
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXECUTE sp_configure 'clr enabled', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
```

We run this in the T-SQL editor on the Azure platform, and receive the following:

```
Failed to execute query. Error: Statement 'CONFIG' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

When we run the following, we see that is enabled.

```
SELECT name,
CAST(value as int) as value_configured,
CAST(value_in_use as int) as value_in_use
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'clr enabled';
```

[image]

How to we update these settings?

thanks.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here... I assume you are using an Azure SQL Database, rather than SQL Server hosted in Azure. Though Azure SQL Database's don't support OLE Automation Procedures as far as I am aware. (Certainly my instance doesn't have the objects).

Comment: I think CLR is a better example. It is enabled currently and we are failing to see how to disable it. I'll update my question with that example

Comment: CLR is also, not supported. [Resolving Transact-SQL differences during migration to SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server): *"**Transact-SQL syntax not supported in Azure SQL Database**: .NET Framework: CLR integration with SQL Server."*

Comment: That document I linked also states (under the same heading): *"`sp_configure` options and `RECONFIGURE`. Some options are available using [ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql)."*

Comment: My instance, too, returns `1`, but that doesn't change the fact it is *not* supported.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sp_configure (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-configure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is not supported in Azure SQL database:
[image]

We can not run the `sp_configure` statements. But [sys.configurations (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-configurations-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table is supported.
[image]

We can see the default value is 1 for `clr enabled`.

And like @Larnu said, CLR is also not supported: [Resolving Transact-SQL differences during migration to SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server).

Ref this question: [Does or does not SQL Azure support CLR assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342550/does-or-does-not-sql-azure-support-clr-assemblies)

Just for now, we can not change this settings in Azure SQL database.

HTH.